# Fragment Android refresh

Tags: android, fragment

I'm implementing fragment in android, i be faced issue:

```
public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            switch (num)
            {
                case 0:
                    NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment();
                    //newFragment.refresh();
                    return newFragment;
                case 1:
                    HotFragment hotFragment = new HotFragment();
                    //hotFragment.refresh();
                    return hotFragment;
                default: return new ContentFragment();
            }

        }
```

When i click button in tab host, it call "onCreateView" and "onViewCreated" only once. But with my purpose can i call back function to handle every time i call new NewFragment() ?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //some config
}
```

I did try onDetach(), onAttach(), onResume(), but it not work by my purpose

Comment: what do you want to do? rephrase your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand you, but if you want to refresh your fragment you can you this:

```
                getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .detach(TheFragment.this)
                    .attach(TheFragment.this)
                    .commit();
```